# PDFBOX - Extract text from Single PDF with Multiple Pages(Java)

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am extracting text from pdf document using pdfbox. With exisiting code only first page text is coming and other pages are not. 
What code should be added in this code to achieve the all pages display i.
**exisiting code**

```js
public class PDFBoxReadFromFile {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\ed\\Documents\\test2.pdf"))) {

      if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
        PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        Rectangle2D rect4 = new Rectangle2D.Double(210, 160, 230, 25);
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(55, 290, 225, 17);

        Rectangle2D rect2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(281, 255, 255, 20);
        Rectangle2D rect3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(2, 365, 660, 1900);
        stripper.addRegion("class2", rect1);
        stripper.addRegion("class3", rect2);
        stripper.addRegion("class4", rect3);
        stripper.addRegion("class5", rect4);
        PDPage firstPage = document.getPages().get(0);
        stripper.extractRegions(firstPage);
        System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class5"));
        System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class2"));
        System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class3"));
        System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class4"));

        File file = new File("C:/Users/ed/eclipse-workspace/pdfboxreadfromfile/file.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class5"));
        pw.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class2"));
        pw.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class3"));
        pw.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class4"));
        pw.close();

      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);
    }
  }
```

with loop

```js
PDPageTree allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
int pageNumber = document.getNumberOfPages();

for (int i = 0; i < pageNumber; i++) {

  PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);

  stripper.extractRegions(page);
}
```

**get(0) output (only shows - Page1)**

```js
PO - 00343423 | Vendor: eL - 00074 | Expected DeliveryDate...: 5 / 10 / 2020 | Date...................................: 5 / 10 / 2020
95123 305198 93.00 CK30 60.00 180.00 0.00 0.00
30 250
95024 305200 93.00 K30250ML 60.00 180.00 0.00 0.00
30 250
95048 305201 13.00 CK30250ML 60.00 180.00 0.00 0.00
30 250
65336 304100 20.00 CK24 54.00 540.00 0.00 0.00
350
178749 300145 16.00 PK6BOE 250 ML 18.00 108.00 0.00 0.00
250
```

**get(1) output(only shows fews contents from page 2)**
RE ERAL 
0ML 20.00
PK12 6.00|||20.00 eS 12.00 240.00 0.00

**get(2) output**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1-based index out of bounds: 3
    at pdfbox.app@2.0.19/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree.get(PDPageTree.java:307)
    at pdfbox.app@2.0.19/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree.get(PDPageTree.java:232)
    at pdfboxreadfromfile.PDFBoxReadFromFile.main(PDFBoxReadFromFile.java:95)

PDF FILE - PAGE 1
[image]
PAGE 2
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214792/discussion-on-question-by-leace-pdfbox-extract-text-from-single-pdf-with-multi).